# how to add childs to canvas in varius orders

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

I need help to add childs to canvas.
I want to add childs to canvas in top-down direction and left-right direction?
I'm using the addChild function but I don't want to calculate the X and the Y for each Item.
is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [mx:HBox](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/HBox.html) or a [mx:VBox](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/containers/VBox.html) to your canvas.

These components lay their children out like you require:

```
<mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:VBox id="verticalLayout" width="100%" height="100%" />
</mx:Canvas>
```

Calling "addChild" on the "verticalLayout" component will add each child under the previous.

Comment: Using Tile would be a better option since the OP mentioned top-down and left-right direction.